# Visual Studio 2013: Item Template for specific Project Template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Is it possible to create Item Templates that only appear for specific Project Templates?

I can't seem to find any information on this.

Answer (score 0):

No, because there is no deterministic way to associate a project file on disk with the project template (if any) that created it. You can only associate an Item Template with a specific type of project (e.g. C# or Visual Basic).